# Implied closure in weak topology?

Tags: general-topology

The setting: Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be a set, $Y$ be a topological space and $(f_a)_{a\in A}$ a family of functions $f_a:X\to Y$. We equip $X$ with the weak topology that $(f_a)$ define. Suppose that $Y$ is Hausdorff and that $(f_a)$ separates the points of $X$, hence $X$ becomes also Hausdorff.

The question: Suppose $A\subset K\subset X$ and $K$ is a compact set in $X$. Also suppose that for all $a\in A$ it is $\overline{f_a(A)}=f_a(K)$. Is it true then that $\overline{A}=K$?
There's not much to say, I can't think of something useful. I think that nets induce more chaos here, I tried working with sub-basic neighborhoods of the weak topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample to show this fails quite miserably:

$X =\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$, $f_1 = \pi_1$ the projection onto the first coordinate, $f_2=\pi_2$, the other projection. This separates points, $Y$ is Hausdorff and $X$ has the product topology which is exactly the weak topology from the two projections.

Now let $K=[0,1]^2$ (compact), $A=\{(x,x):x \in [0,1]\} \subseteq K$ also closed while $f_1[A]=f_1[K]=[0,1]$ and likewise for $f_2$. But $\overline{A}=A \neq K$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see if we can add some hypotheses to get the desired result?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn If we add that the $f_\alpha$ separate points and closed sets as well, the product map of $X$ into $Y^A$ becomes an embedding and that might be enough?